# AWS iot boto3 - how to get a certificate attached to a thing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-iot

What is the best way to get a certificate arn attached to a thing? AWS documentation doesnt have a method to get the certificate attached to a particular thing.

Answer (score 3):

oops I found it. It is [list_thing_principals][1] https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot.html#IoT.Client.list_thing_principals